# Accessing and updating Keyword in the Document Object

Tags: document

I've a got a strange question, (at least I assume it's strange, I can't find anything like it online)
Essentially I'm looking to access the Keywords section of the Document object, I have a trigger that is started by a document being uploaded.

I read the content of the file to programmatically calculate the highest occurring words in the file (checked against a list of common words that are exempt).

So I used to the DocumentContentLink to let me read the body. Is there a means for me to insert the word(s) that I have gleaned into the Keyword?

The developer console only allows Select and Find so I can't figure out how to reach this value to insert anything.

I can see from the document docs that the keyword is selectable from here.

```
select name,body,authorID, keywords
from Document where id = '01541000001mo73'
```

If this is not reachable is there a way I can create a relationship between the calculated keywords and the file at least?

Anything at all would be a great help! I've been wracking my brains for this for a while. Thank you so much!
[image: Keywords]

Comment: The keywords field is updatable. Have you tried anything (Like [var].keywords = 'ABCD')? Are you getting an error - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_document.htm

Comment: I'm coming from the ContentDocument Object and trying to get the ID for the Document object in order to be able to change the keywords.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works out for me

```
Id docId = '01563000000Dv9G'; // hardcoded doc ID
Document doc = [select name,body,authorID, keywords from Document where id=:docId];

System.debug(doc.keywords); // null
System.debug(doc.id); // 01563000000Dv9G

doc.keywords ='salesforce';
update doc;

Document updatedDoc = [select name,body,authorID, keywords from Document where id = :docId];

System.debug(updatedDoc.keywords); // output is "salesforce"
```